# How do I do a full git clone of my file based git repo in an OpenShift build of Jenkins shared libraries?

Tags: jenkins, shared-libraries

When building a custom Jenkins image to include our shared libraries onboard using a Dockerfile to pull the repo into the Jenkins container image the build works fine. However, whenever Jenkins tries to use the shared libraries in a build, I get a message "status code 128" when a build tries to run "git ls-remote" command on our shared library repo. It indicates that it cannot do this on a shallow git repo. How can I prevent a shallow repo from being put there?

Answer (score 0):

When OpenShift does a clone of a repo into the build environment, it does a shallow clone. This means that your Dockerfile's access is only to the shallow git clone and not the entire clone and so it copies that in. You can tell OpenShift not to do a shallow clone by adding a `ref:` to the git section of your BuildConfig. This forces a full git clone and will make the full repo available to load into your Jenkins container.